# How can I update a User Form at Runtime?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

For my C# Outlook AddIn I have several User Forms where the User is able to add Words to a Blacklist. I need those Blacklists for several functions.

My problem is that after adding a word to one of the blacklists the added word isn't shown right away. The added word is only visible after closing the form and reopen it once again.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than that. What are the relevant code snippets that do not function as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to invalidate the form after a word was added to the blacklist. For that you can expose a public method on your form which can be called from different places in the code where word are added to the blacklist. In the exposed method you can do the required modification to update the UI according to the word blacklisted.